# Saving data from frontend in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have `testimonials` table where I get reviews from users, for backend(admins) everything works perfectly, my issue is with front-end form where users (logged or guests) can send their testimonials, somehow it doesn't works and also not shows any error to see which part has issue.

Here are my codes:

`Routes`

```
Route::get('/write-testimonials', 'frontend\FrontendController@testimonialcreate')->name('write-testimonials');
Route::post('/write-testimonials', 'frontend\FrontendController@testimonialcreate')->name('write-testimonialsstore');
```

Controller:

```
public function testimonialcreate()
    {
      return view('front.testimonials-create');
    }

    public function testimonialcreatestore(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'body'=>'required',
          'user_email' => 'nullable',
          'user_name' => 'nullable',
          'image' => 'nullable|image',
          'status_id' => 'required|numeric',
          'user_id' => 'nullable|numeric',
        ));
        $testimonial = new Testimonial;

        $testimonial->body = $request->input('body');
        $testimonial->user_email = $request->input('user_email');
        $testimonial->user_name = $request->input('user_name');
        $testimonial->status_id = $request->input('status_id');
        $testimonial->user_id = $request->input('user_id');

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
          $image = $request->file('image');
          $filename = 'Testimonial' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $location = public_path('images/');
          $request->file('image')->move($location, $filename);

          $testimonial->image = $filename;
        }

        $testimonial->save();
        return redirect()->back()
            ->with('success', 'Testimonial sent!');
    }
```

And my `blade`

```
<form  action="{{route('write-testimonialsstore')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="col-md-8">
        @guest
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                {{Form::label('user_email', 'Email')}}
                {{Form::text('user_email', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                {{Form::label('user_name', 'Name')}}
                {{Form::text('user_name', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                {{Form::label('image', 'Image')}}
                {{Form::file('image', array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
              </div>
            </div>
        @endguest

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="mt-20">
              {{Form::label('body', 'Write your testimonial')}}
              {{Form::textarea('body', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <label for="status_id" hidden>Status</label>
            <input type="hidden" name=status_id" value="1">
          @auth
            <label for="user_id" hidden>User</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" placeholder="{{ Auth::user()->username }}">
          @endauth
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="mt-20">
        {{ Form::submit('Send', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
    </div>
</form>
```

any idea?

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens? What does your error log say?

Comment: Do you ask us to debug your code? What do you mean by "doesn't work"? You have to describe it clear.

Comment: @fubar there is no error + nothing will be save in database that's the issue.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan data will not store in database\

Comment: hey bro how you're doing .. last year was a busy year for me i'm sorry couldn't help you with your previous questions, anyway, i think the problem here is that your route is calling a different method from what is in the controller .. routes: `testimonialcreate` while in your controller you have `testimonialcreatestore`

Comment: @Demonyowh hi bro, happy new year :), I guess you're right it was silly of me :-D. where can I chat with you again?

Comment: it is already answered below bro ..

Comment: @shukshin.ivan that's basic :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you misunderstood the route names.

```
Route::post('/write-testimonials', 'frontend\FrontendController@testimonialcreate')->name('write-testimonialsstore');
```

The name after `@` sign is action name. Post request have to use another action name. So just change it from `@testimonialcreate` to `@testimonialcreatestore` for the `Route::post` line/